# apply-templates vs next-match in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Given an XML like this:

```
<a id="1">
  <b>
    <code>42</code>
  </b>
</a>
```

And the target being:

```
<request>
  <aId>1</aId>
  <bCode>42</bCode>
</request>
```

I can reach that using this XSLT:

```
<template match="/">
  <element name="request">
    <apply-templates/>
  </element>
</template>

<template match="a">
  <element name="aId"><value-of select="@id"/></element>
  <apply-templates/>
</template>

<template match="b/code">
  <element name="bCode"><value-of select="."/></element>
</template>
```

However, this also works if I swap `<apply-templates/>` with `<next-match/>`. Any advice on which to use when, when they both seem to work fine? Does `next-match` have additional effects which can mess things up if I add more stuff later for example?

Comment: `xsl:next-match` is useful when you need to perform "staged processing" -- and this is clearly not your current case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in that case your use of `next-match` relies on the built-in element template doing `apply-templates` (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule). And once you added a template for elements e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

the `next-match` would no longer use the built-in template which does nothing but `apply-templates` but would choose above template which adds result nodes.

So for your code I would continue to use `apply-templates`.

Comment: Right, had a feeling `apply-templates` was safer. Makes sense :)